# Closing a dialog shown by Wix installer before launching an exe

Tags: c#, winforms, wix, windows-installer, windows

I have created a wix project from where i am executing a custom action which displays forms that are created in C#.
So when i launch the MSI, it shows a small dialog that says:-
Please wait while windows configures "APPNAME"

And then the C# form is displayed but this dialog is there in the background.
when all the C# forms are over, then also this dialog is shown.

So how can i prevent this dialog to show.

Please help.